# Setting up two external USB hard drive as RAID 1

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, raid, mirroring

Is this possible in Windows 7? I know I can periodically sync my files using software like SyncBack but I'm looking for mirroring on the fly. Is there a similar method like RAID 1 that can achieve fast mirroring for external USB drives?

Comment: I guess this can't be done?

Comment: I [had issues](http://superuser.com/q/429776/83694) when trying RAID 1 on two external USB HDDs, so I gave up...

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, on a second thread to which I will point you in a moment after I type enough such that this website stops converting my "trivial" answer into a comment which cannot be tagged as the answer to the original question.

The thread is here:

[Link to article "Can you link external USB hard drives in a RAID-style system"](http://superuser.com/questions/8592/can-you-link-external-usb-hard-drives-in-a-raid-style-system)

(This was originally posted May 24 2014 as an "answer", but I was told it is better as a comment. So here we go.)