# mdadm RAID 1 not activating spare after replacing faulty drive

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid-1, mdadm

Have issue with mdadm similar to [Simple mdadm RAID 1 not activating spare](https://superuser.com/questions/429776/simple-mdadm-raid-1-not-activating-spare):

- have replaced faulty HDD in RAID 10
- fdisked and added new hdd to mdadmn
- mdam resynced array

After that I see following:

...

```
/dev/md2:
        Version : 0.90
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 683792000 (652.11 GiB 700.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 683792000 (652.11 GiB 700.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

           UUID : e8ba8727:1b7ba76c:2f2051f8:e6dff55c
         Events : 0.94996850

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       34        0      active sync   /dev/sdc2
       2       8       50        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdd2
```

`cat /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action
idle`

Is it possible to convert spare drive to active without stopping an array?

**UPDATE 1**
Posting rebuild logs. Nothing interesting here...

`grep md /var/log/messages`

Jul 19 10:30:19 xen kernel: md: unbind
Jul 19 10:30:19 xen kernel: md: export_rdev(sdd2)
Jul 19 10:32:07 xen kernel: md: bind
Jul 19 10:33:31 xen kernel: md: unbind
Jul 19 10:33:31 xen kernel: md: export_rdev(sdd2)
Jul 19 10:35:01 xen kernel: md: bind
Jul 19 10:35:01 xen kernel: md: recovery of RAID array md2
Jul 19 10:35:01 xen kernel: md: minimum *guaranteed*  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
Jul 19 10:35:01 xen kernel: md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
Jul 19 10:35:01 xen kernel: md: using 128k window, over a total of 683792000 blocks.
...
Jul 19 17:22:36 xen kernel: md: md2: recovery done.

Tried:

- removed ALL drives from array except working first drive( mdadm --grow /dev/md2 --raid-devices=1 --force)
- removed "removed" and "detached" drives
- zeroed superblock on new drive's partition (mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd2)
- growed array to raid-devices=2
- re-added new drive mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdd2

everything is the same :(

`mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 0.90
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 683792000 (652.11 GiB 700.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 683792000 (652.11 GiB 700.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent`

```
Update Time : Thu Jul 19 18:13:46 2018
      State : clean, degraded
```

Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  **Spare Devices : 1**

```
     Events : 0.95212006

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       34        0      active sync   /dev/sdc2
   2       8       50        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdd2
```

Comment: Hey! I'm the guy from [Simple mdadm RAID 1 not activating spare](https://superuser.com/q/429776/83694).  There are a lot of answers there. What have you tried?  What do you see in `dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages` around the time the spare fails to become active?

Comment: Hello, Deltik, thank you for you topic! Tried everything :( Last commands:
mdadm ... -fail /dev/sdd2

mdadm ... -remove /dev/sdd2

mdadm ... -remove failed, -remove detached

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of `dmesg` starting from when the spare fails to rebuild?

Comment: Yes, mdraid is now rebuilding, will update my post with log entries from /var/log/messages after rebuild finished. Thank you!